# CurlException: 77: Problem with the SSL CA cert - facebook connect

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I'm getting the following error message in my httpd error log while trying to use fconnect:

> Uncaught CurlException: 77: Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)\n  thrown in /var/www/html/fbtest/src/base_facebook.php on line 820

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used instructions on the following link.. Streams to the rescue :)

http://www.martinsikora.com/facebook-php-api-without-curl-extension

Answer (score 3):

Another common cause for this is if your server time is off.

The SSL signing is reliant on your server reporting the correct time, so if NTPD isn't running and this gets out of sync for any reason, this error will occur.

A common way to update this manually will be to call the following command:

```
ntpdate pool.ntp.org
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing your fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt file (should be in the same directory as base_facebook.php). If it's there, ensure your webserver has access (permissions) to read it

You can find it here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt

Comment: fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt is in the same folder and user permission is given for apache user.

Comment: Just to be safe, open up base_facebook.php and add:
if (!is_readable(dirname(__FILE__).'/fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt')) throw new Exception('NOT READABLE');

around line 810 of base_facebook.php
__FILE__ is meant to be _ _ FILE _ _ (without spaces, SO converts it to bold)